# Python: remove initial number and underscore from strings in a line (but keep other underscores)

Tags: python

I have a split line (split using `.split()`) that looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '1_a23_4', '2_b234', '300_235_2_2', '1000_1_1_1_1']
```

Each string has a variable number of underscores and different combinations of letters/numbers after the first underscore. For any string with a number followed by an underscore, I want to drop the initial number/underscore to get this result:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a23_4', 'b234', '235_2_2', '1_1_1_1']
```

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405601/remove-characters-before-and-including-in-python-2-7), but I have multiple underscores for some strings in the split line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
d = ['a', 'b', 'c', '1_a23_4', '2_b234', '300_235_2_2', '1000_1_1_1_1']
new_d = [re.sub('^\d+_', '', i) for i in d]
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a23_4', 'b234', '235_2_2', '1_1_1_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l=['a', 'b', 'c', '1_a23_4', '2_b234', '300_235_2_2', '1000_1_1_1_1']
>>> l=["_".join(i.split("_")[1:]) if "_" in i else i for i in l]
>>> l
['a', 'b', 'c', 'a23_4', 'b234', '235_2_2', '1_1_1_1']
```